# Webcomponent as Backbone tagName - no shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm trying to figure out what's going on here. I've been writing a project that uses [Jeremy Fairbank's two-way data binding between Backbone views and Polymer webcomponents](http://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/polymer-web-components-with-marionette-js/). It has been working really well, until I started upgrading to Polymer 1.0.

Consider this example. When the component is declared in the html it works as it should. When it's part of the Backbone view it does not work. Any thoughts as to what's going on here?

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/aftersox/3ddj3yL2/1/)

HTML

```
    <link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">
<dom-module id='test-component'>
    <template>
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <div>Hello, my name is {{name}}</div>
    </template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</dom-module>

    <script id="template-test-layout" type="text/template">
        <div id="spot1">spot1</div>
        <div id="spot2">spot2</div>
    </script>

    <script id="template-test-view" type="text/template">
    </script>

    <test-component name="George Washington"></test-component>

    <div id="app-space"></div>
```

JS

```
// The test component
Polymer({
    is: 'test-component'
});

var TestLayout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    el: "#app-space",
    template: "#template-test-layout",
    regions: {
        spot1: "#spot1",
        spot2: "#spot2"
    }
});

var TestView1 = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#template-test-view",
    tagName: "test-component"
});

var layout = new TestLayout();
layout.render();

var testView1 = new TestView1();
layout.getRegion('spot1').show(testView1);
```

Comment: Im not too familiar with Polymer, can you show me an example that is working vs one that is not when its declared in the HTML?

Comment: The working component is shown in the HTML, it's <test-component></test-component> and it displays properly. But when it's added as part of a Backbone view it doesn't display correctly.